# Can I use REST Assured to create a client?

Tags: java, ssl, rest-assured

I need to create a client and pass a truststore and a keystore.

I cant use

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="changeit"
```

because i have to change my truststore in execution time.

I saw that REST Assured has support for truststore.

```
RestAssured.given().keyStore(path\\to\\keystore).trustStore(path\\to\\truststore,password)
```

Can I use it in my client?

> REST Assured -
> Testing and validating REST services in Java is harder than in dynamic languages such as Ruby and Groovy. REST Assured brings the simplicity of using these languages into the Java domain. For example, if your HTTP server returns the following JSON at “http://localhost:8080/lotto/{id}”:

Is there any other class that manager it?